# Obtain error cause inside Fastly vcl_error subroutine

Tags: varnish-vcl, fastly, fastly-vcl

Fastly allows to customise `vcl_error` subroutine. However, If I override it (e.g.

```
sub vcl_error {
#FASTLY error
  set obj.http.Custom-Header = "foo-bar";
  return(deliver);
}
```

), original response body with error cause (e.g. "first byte timout") is lost.

Is it possible to obtain a cause, so I can add it to additional some header or `syntetic` body

Answer (score 2):

The [`vcl_error`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/subroutines/error/) subroutine is triggered either implicitly by Fastly (see [the documentation](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/subroutines/error/) for examples of when it does this) or *explicitly* using the [`error`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/statements/error/) statement.

Within `vcl_error` the [`obj.status`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/variables/cache-object/obj-status/) and [`obj.response`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/variables/cache-object/obj-response/) variables provide information about the nature of the error.

If you're explicitly triggering `vcl_error`, then from within the subroutine you're invoking the `error` statement you should set a custom HTTP header on an object that you can read back from within `vcl_error`.

For example, the `req` object is available to all subroutines so you could use [`req.http.{NAME}`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/variables/client-request/req-http/)) to store off any contextual error information you want to use as part of your synthetic error response.

One caveat with persisting data in this fashion is that you can't persist data across certain boundaries, such as the move from a subroutine on a 'fetching node' to a 'delivery node' (see [clustering](https://developer.fastly.com/learning/vcl/clustering/) for details of what the difference between fetching/delivery nodes).

Off the top of my head (see also: https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/fastly-varnish/#breadcrumb-trail) I believe if you're invoking `error` from `vcl_fetch` you'll need to persist the data to the `beresp` object and not `req`. Varnish will copy `beresp` to the `obj` object that is exposed to the `vcl_error` subroutine.

If you have any other questions or concerns, then please reach out to support@fastly.com who will be happy to help.

Please also refer to the [Fastly 'Developer Hub'](https://developer.fastly.com/) which has a bunch of resources on [Varnish](https://developer.fastly.com/learning/vcl/) and [VCL](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/) that might be useful to you.